# Looking for a male USB B connector

Tags: usb, connector, components

I'm trying to get a connector that will connect another product as a sort of 'daughter board'.  This thing has the old USB B connector on it and what I'd like to do is back it up to this connector and (since it's male) use it as a point of mechanical contact too.

I'd like something like in the attached picture, but PCB solder mounted.....I've looked for about an hour and a half and can't find anything.

Has anyone ever seen such a creature?

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic in this forum and will be closed.  Reference: Help->Tour->Don't ask about...Shopping or buying recommendations.

Comment: This question can't be closed.

Comment: This is not in violation of the rules.  This is not a question regarding recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them.  This is a question about the general existence of a particular variation of an electronic component.  Please read the whole post in context before posting distracting and non constructive comments and wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a non-standard connector, and you will only find it in a specialty shop, or by special order. The closest standard part is plugs used for cables, before plastic is molded to them.

[image]

The USB standard does not have non-cable male usb B. And it's not meant to be used as a mechanical support point. It will easily bend off.